# When does $X_n\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}X$ and $Y_n\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}Y$ imply $X_n+Y_n\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}X+Y$?

Tags: distributions, convergence, asymptotics, slutsky-theorem

The question:

$X_n\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}X$ and $Y_n\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}Y \stackrel{?}{\implies} X_n+Y_n\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}X+Y$

I know that this does not hold in general; Slutsky's theorem only applies when one or both of the convergences is in probability.

However, are there instances in which it *does* hold?

For instance, if the sequences $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Formalizing @Ben answer, independence is *almost* a sufficient condition, because we know that the characteristic function of the sum of two independent RV's is the product of their marginal characteristic functions. Let $$Z_n = X_n + Y_n$$. Under independence of $X_n$ and $Y_n$,

$$\phi_{Z_n}(t) = \phi_{X_n}(t)\phi_{Y_n}(t)$$

So

$$\lim \phi_{Z_n}(t) =\lim \Big [\phi_{X_n}(t)\phi_{Y_n}(t)\Big]$$

and we have (since we assume that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ converge)

$$\lim \Big [\phi_{X_n}(t)\phi_{Y_n}(t)\Big] = \lim \phi_{X_n}(t)\cdot \lim \phi_{Y_n}(t) = \phi_{X}(t)\cdot \phi_{Y}(t) $$

which is the characteristic function of $X+Y$... *if* $X+Y$ are independent. And they will be independent if *one of the two* has a continuous distribution function ([see this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/396617/28746)). This is the condition required in addition to independence of the sequences, so that independence is preserved at the limit.

Without independence we would have

$$\phi_{Z_n}(t) \neq \phi_{X_n}(t)\phi_{Y_n}(t)$$

and no general assertion can be made about the limit.

Comment: Great answer (+1).  I think with this method it's also worth noting that the weaker assumption $\lim \phi_{Z_n} = \lim \phi_{X_n} \phi_{Y_n}$ (asymptotic independence) goes directly to your second step and so also gives you the result.  This shows that asymptotic independence is sufficient for the desired property.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, independence is sufficient:** The antecedent conditions here concern convergence in distribution for the *marginal* distributions of $\{ X_n \}$ and $\{ Y_n \}$.  The reason that the implication does not hold generally is that there is nothing in the antecedent conditions that deals with the statistical dependence between the elements of the two sequences.  If you were to impose independence of the sequences then that would be sufficient to ensure convergence in distribution of the sum.

([Alecos](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/28746/alecos-papadopoulos) has added an excellent answer below that proves this result using characteristic functions.  Asymptotic independence is also sufficient for this implication, since the same limiting decomposition of the characteristic functions occurs.)

Comment: Independence *of the sequences* may not be sufficient. You also need independence of the limiting $X$ and $Y$. If the sequences are independent but $X = -Y$ you are cooked.

Comment: @guy: I think you'll find (see Alecos answer below) that the independence of the limiting sequences, plus convergence of the sequences, implies that you cannot have that latter outcome.

Comment: The conclusion that $\varphi_X \cdot \varphi_Y$ is the cdf of $X + Y$ In @Alecos answer relies on the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. So it requires $X$ and $Y$ to be independent, if the mode of convergence is $\stackrel{d}{\to}$. Suppose $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are iid $N(0,1)$, then $X_n \stackrel d \to X_1$ and $Y_n \stackrel d \to -X_1$, but $X_n + Y_n \stackrel d \to N(0,2)$ while $X + Y = 0$.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you're saying.  It appears that the OP has not specified that $X$ and $Y$ are to be taken to be independent in his conclusion "$\overset{d}{\rightarrow} X+Y$".  I presume that was his intention.  You're right that this needs to be specified.

Comment: @guy If $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are as you describe in your comment, it appears that their limits remain two independent $N(0,1)$, since convergence here is trivial (does not depend on $n$). I don't get how $X_1$ emerges.

Comment: @Alecos If you agree that they converge to a $N(0,1)$ then you trivially agree that they both converge in distribution to $X_1$ by definition. They also both converge in distribution to $-X_1$, and to all other $N(0,1)$ random variables. Convergence in distribution is not like other modes of convergence, you can converge in distribution to many different random variables; the limiting random variable does not even need to be defined on the same probability space. The only thing which is unique is the **marginal distribution**.

Comment: @Alecos put another way, note that the distribution of $X+Y$ is not even well defined just by talking about the sequences being independent. You can have $X_n \to X$ and $Y_n \to Y$ without making any assumption at all about the dependence structure of $X$ and $Y$, even if you make strong assumptions about the dependence of $X_n$ and $Y_n$. All we’ve done is pinned down the marginals of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @guy Certainly. What I really wonder about is the following: If we have two sequences $\{X_1,...,X_n\}$ and $\{Y_1,...,Y_n\}$, where the marginals depend on the index, and a) we assume that the pairs $(X_i,Y_i)$ are independent, and b) we assume that each sequence converges to $X$ and $Y$ respectively, is it possible that these limiting random variables are dependent? How could we lose independence at the limit?

Comment: @Alecos My example is of that nature :)

Comment: @guy Ok, I' ll try to understand it, but I don't see it yet. At the moment, what I am thinking is that converging to random variables that have the same distribution does not mean that they converge to the same random variable.

Comment: @Alecos the definition of convergence in distribution of random variables is that $X_n \to X$ is defined to mean that $F_n(x) \to F(x)$ (at the continuity points) where $F_n$ is the cdf of $X_n$ and $F$ is the cdf of $X$. Hence, if $X_n \to Z$ where $Z \sim N(0,1)$ then by definition you also have $X_n \to -Z$. If $\{X_n\}$ and $\{Y_n\}$ are iid $N(0,1)$ but $X_n + Y_n \to Z + (-Z) = 0$ is false.

Comment: @guy Thanks for insisting, I understand now: it is a statement about convergence of the marginal distribution function, which will be the same for identically distributed RVs irrespective of their probabilistic relation. It is a statement of what is the distribution of the limit, not what is the limiting RV. I have posted a question inspired by our chat here, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/396617/28746 .  Thanks!

Comment: @Ben You may be interested in this thread, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/396617/28746

Comment: @guy Your reasoning makes sense, yet the conclusion in your example intuitively seems odd. You are saying that if I have two sequences of iid standard normal random variables, they necessarily converge in distribution to the constant zero?

Comment: Oh; I think I understand. You are saying that I need an added condition on the independence of $X$ and $Y$ for my original statement in the question to hold. Please let me know if I understand correctly.

Comment: @mikario The point is that they don't converge to $0$, which shows that the condition that $\{X_n\}$ and $\{Y_n\}$ are independent is not sufficient to guarantee that $X_n + Y_n \to X + Y$; you also need that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: @guy Ok, I get it. Thanks for the insightful comments :)

Answer (score 5):

The [Cramer-Wold theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Wold_theorem) gives a necessary and sufficient condition:

Let $\{z_n\}$ be a sequence of $R^K$-valued random variables. Then,
$$
z_n \to_d z\;\Longleftrightarrow\;\lambda'z_n\to_d \lambda'z\quad\forall\quad \lambda\in R^K\backslash\{0\}
$$

To give an example, let $U\sim N(0,1)$ and define $W_n:=U$ as well as $V_n:=(-1)^nU$. We then trivially have $$W_n\to_d U$$ and, due to symmetry of the standard normal distribution, that
$$V_n\to_d U.$$ 
However, $W_n+V_n$ does not converge in distribution, as
$$
W_n+V_n=\begin{cases}2U\sim N(0,4)&\text{for}\;n\;\text{even}\\
0&\text{for}\;n\;\text{odd}\end{cases}
$$
This is an application of the Cramer-Wold Device for $\lambda=(1,\;1)'$.